# /usr/local/lib contains libraries which Aptitude reports aren't installed

Tags: package-management, aptitude, shared-library

I am trying to build a project that uses a specific library (SDL) on Ubuntu. The project uses old version of the library (libSDL-1.2). I've made mistake of installing the newest library but have since removed it. However, I can still find traces of it in multiple Ubuntu library directories.

[image]

In some directories there is proper version (*/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/*) while in others there is the newest, wrong, version (*/usr/local/lib/*). Why do I have this inconsistencies and how do I completely remove libSDL2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/local/` contains files that are not installed by the package manager, be it due to a manual installation or additional files downloaded by e.g. an installer script from a package (although those mostly go to `/opt/`).

APT is therefore unaware of the files below that directory. If you installed the libraries manually, e.g. by extracting an archive there, you should also be able to remove them in the same way.
Pay, however, attention if you didn't install them manually. In this case please tell us how you installed them to receive further and better help.

Another possibility is that the libraries could be there because they may have been downloaded by something else, and not from installing libsdl2 using APT. E.g. Valve's Source Engine uses SDL2. When you install a Source-based game, e.g. Half Life or Portal, Steam will download its own libraries (although it keeps them in the users home directory). The may come from something similar. If you have no idea where they come from, leave them be. They will not disturb your development, if done correctly (see below) and deletion may break some other application.

If you want to continue using SDL1.2, you sould be able to do so without removing the other libs: Tell the compiler/linker to use the older libraries. SDL2 shared libraries are always called `libsdl2-....so`, so simply link against the correct libraries without the `sdl2` in there.

Comment: +1 for you for a way better description then what I was going to say originally.  :)

Comment: Thanks. However, IIRC, I installed SDL2 with `apt-get install sdl2-xxx` and removed with `apt-get remove sdl2-xxx`. Why it didn't remove these files is beyond me.

Comment: Because these aren't the libraries installed by your command; these were installed in `/usr/lib`.